# Failed writing body in libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am using libcurl for a small program that gets data from an input url. But i sometimes get an error from the pErrorBuffer like:

```
Failed writing to body (something != somethingelse)
```

What does this mean? I mean in what situation is this error created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means your [write callback](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION) didn't return the same number of bytes as was passed into it!